# How to construct an Android applicationId wisely

Tags: android, flutter, android-build

Android apps have an `applicationId` that looks like `com.example.app`. I'm currently looking at how to correctly define one as this cannot be changed after release. In particular since we also have a website what I'm interested about is the relation between the website URL and the application id, since it seems that it affects SEO.

Let's say that our website is `http://example.com`. I thought that naturally the applicationId should be `com.example` (only two segments).

However the following [link](https://www.skoumal.com/en/how-to-construct-applicationid-wisely/) tells the following recommendation regarding appId:

```
example: com.example.app
We recommend adding app or android as a postfix for main project/company apps as in the example above.
```

Why is that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more likely it is unique, the better. Using 2 segment is the minumum requirement but using 3 segment is ideal for more guarantee way for unique identifier (look like java packages). There is nothing to worry about it. Do **com.example.myapp** and pass it. Such as I use like that: **com.mycompanyname.myprojectname**